# Is this a pdf? What am I missing?

Tags: self-study, distributions

$f(x_1,x_2)=3(x_1+x_2)$ defined for $0<x_1,x_2<1$, $0<x_1+x_2<1$

I am trying to integrate this $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_2} f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$ but I am not getting 1. Are my limits wrong?

Comment: Show your work; it looks like it integrates to 1 to me.

Comment: @Glen_b using the same limits I used?

Comment: Ok, yes. It does integrate correctly. My bad.

Comment: The graph of $f$ subtends a right regular pyramid of height $3$.  Its base is an isosceles right triangle of sides $1$. Thus the [volume](https://www.google.com/search?q=pyramid+volume) is $1/3\times (1\times 1\times 3)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x_1,x_2)=3(x_1+x_2)$ defined for $0<x_1,x_2<1$, $0<x_1+x_2<1$

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_2} f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$

$=3\int_0^1 (1-x_2)^2/2+(1-x_2)x_2dx_2$

$=3[-(1-x_2)^3/6+x_2^2/2-x_2^3/3]|_0^1$

$=3[1/2-1/3+1/6]=1$